# Spring Security's HttpSecurity config not doing what expected

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm struggling with the `HttpSecurity` config.

The following configuration is what I want to achieve:

- **Path:**"/**", **Access rules:**  [{Everyone, GET}]
- **Path:**"/rest/metadata**", **Access rules:**  [{Everyone, GET},{ROLE_ADMIN, All HTTP methods}]
- **Path:**"/rest/**", **Access rules:**  [{Unauthenticated, Only GET},{Authenticated, all Http Methods}]
- **Path:**"/*" (Web resources, login), **Access rules:** [{Everyone, all Http Methods}]

Out of this requirements, I made the following config in Spring Security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SctSecurityConfig extends LdapSecurityConfig {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/metadata**").hasAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.name())
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable();
    }
}
```

The security context for authenticated and unauthenticated access works in general.
Except the rule with `.hasAuthority(UserRole.ADMIN.name())` is getting ignored. I also can make PUT/POST etc. on `/rest/metadata**` with an authenticated user that does not have that role. My understanding was, that those requests should get filter out with that rule. Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: `/rest/metadata**` makes no sense, it should be `/rest/metadata/**"`.

Comment: @dur You are right, that was the problem. With the `/` it works as it should. Thanks. Wanna post this as answer?